# JaVers configuration for spring data JDBC

Tags: javers, spring-data-jdbc

I am trying to use JaVers with Spring Boot project with Spring Data JDBC included.
So, default JaversSqlAutoConfiguration.java do not fit which is for jpa hibernate.
Could you please help to identify JaVers configuration for Spring Boot project with Spring Data JDBC?